# How to retrieve data from two or more tables in asp.net web forms?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I'm currently doing a tutorial on this link and got a question for everyone.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/model-binding/retrieving-data

Right now, I have two different tables: Sales and Staff.
My question is how do I retrieve all the data from these two tables such that SaleID and StaffID matches the same and display the data?
For example, I wish to retrieve data where SaleID= '1' and StaffID= '1'.

In the tutorial, one of the example is shown below and I hope to modify the statement in order to achieve the results.

```
public IQueryable<Student> studentsGrid_GetData()
{
SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();
var query = db.Students.Include(s => s.Enrollments.Select(e => e.Course));
return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `join`, like this:

```
var query = from a in db.Sales 
            join b in db.Staff on a.SaleID equals b.StaffID 
            select a, b;
```